Can Ancient Joker choose a Suit you don’t have?
The Ancient Joker’s description says:

Each played card with [a given suit] gives X1.5 Mult when scored, suit changes at end of round

Can the Ancient Joker select a suit that I don’t have? For example, can it select Diamonds if I don’t have any Diamonds in my deck?

Yes, the Ancient Joker can select a suit you don’t have in your deck.
Source: I had the Ancient Joker select Diamonds while I had no Diamonds or Wild Cards in my deck.


